# SSRS Home Page Not Loading

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, ssrs-2019

Having issue with the SSRS Web Portal URL not loading.  The Web Service URL loads (eventually) but not the Web Portal.  I am upgrading from SSRS 2012 to 2019 and followed the steps [found here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/upgrade-and-migrate-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver16)

As a test I also created a blank ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB databases and that will not load either.

I setup a SQL trace to see if I am hitting the database (DB engine and SSRS service are on same VM along with my testing) and it keeps running the same following commands over and over:

```
exec GetCurrentProductInfo 
exec GetAllConfigurationInfo 
exec GetAnnouncedKey @InstallationID='<uid number of some sort>'

declare @p5 int
set @p5=NULL
exec AnnounceOrGetKey @MachineName=N'<my VM name>', @InstanceName=N'SSRS', @InstallationID='<uid from above',@PublicKey=<public key>,@NumAnnouncedServices=@p5 output
select @p5

exec PollEventsForRSProcess @NumberOfEvents=4

And This Command:

declare @BatchID uniqueidentifier

set @BatchID = newid()

UPDATE [Notifications] WITH (TABLOCKX)
    SET [BatchID] = @BatchID,
    [ProcessStart] = GETUTCDATE(),
    [ProcessHeartbeat] = GETUTCDATE()
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 4  [NotificationID] FROM [Notifications] WITH (TABLOCKX) WHERE ProcessStart is NULL and
    (ProcessAfter is NULL or ProcessAfter < GETUTCDATE()) ORDER BY [NotificationEntered]
) AS t1
WHERE [Notifications].[NotificationID] = t1.[NotificationID]

select top 4
        -- Notification data
        N.[NotificationID],
        N.[SubscriptionID],
        N.[ActivationID],
        N.[ReportID],
        N.[SnapShotDate],
        N.[DeliveryExtension],
        N.[ExtensionSettings],
        N.[Locale],
        N.[Parameters],
        N.[SubscriptionLastRunTime],
        N.[ProcessStart],
        N.[NotificationEntered],
        N.[Attempt],
        N.[IsDataDriven],
        SUSER_SNAME(Owner.[Sid]),
        Owner.[UserName],
        -- Report Data
        O.[Path],
        N.[ReportZone],
        O.[Type],
        SD.NtSecDescPrimary,
        N.[Version],
        Owner.[AuthType],
        SR.[SubscriptionResult]
    from 
        [Notifications] N with (TABLOCKX) inner join [Catalog] O on O.[ItemID] = N.[ReportID]
        inner join [Users] Owner on N.SubscriptionOwnerID = Owner.UserID
        left outer join [SecData] SD on O.[PolicyID] = SD.[PolicyID] AND SD.AuthType = Owner.AuthType
        left outer join [SubscriptionResults] SR on N.[SubscriptionID] = SR.[SubscriptionID] AND CHECKSUM(convert(nvarchar(max),N.[ExtensionSettings])) = SR.[ExtensionSettingsHash]
    where 
        N.[BatchID] = @BatchID
ORDER BY [NotificationEntered]
```

Seems like a continuous loop.  I eventually stopped the trace after a few dozen iterations through those same commands.

Thinking it might be something in setup I temporarily added an execution account that matched an SA account in SQL but that did not help.  My SSRS Service is running as the same account from the old 2012 service and lastly I deleted the encryption keys in hopes I could get something to show since I have all the data source passwords and there are only a few and a hand full of reports.

Did verify SSRS Service account had correct permissions in SQL.

Comment: What happens with the web portal?...do you get an error and if so what is it?

Comment: No error, just an icon in the center of the web page that just spins forever.

Comment: Update:  Added AD account running SSRS service to Local Admin group, unfortunately no luck on that step.